# Somar valores com jquery

Tags: html, jquery, matemática

Eu tenho um input do tipo number que e um select com duas opções e valores diferentes, eu tenho que somar o valor do meu input com o valor do meu select mas sempre que tento, ele me reporta esse erro "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null".

Aqui está o codigo:

```js
var preco = $('#def_preco-21 :selected').val();

calc_preco();



function calc_preco() {

  var quantidade_21 = $('.quant_g-21').val();
  var valor_unitario_21 = preco;
  var valor_total_21 = accounting.formatNumber(valor_unitario_21 * quantidade_21, 2, '', ',');

  document.getElementById('valor_21').value = valor_total_21;

};



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quant_g-21').change(function() {
    calc_preco();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class='cont_prod-list'>
  <div class='div_pai-opt'>
    <div class='opt_prod'>
      <select class='tam_nec' id='def_preco-21'>
        <option value='8'>Produto 1</option>
        <option value='7'>Produto 2</option>
      </select>
      <div id='preco_g-21' class='preco_g-21 preco_g' type='text' name='preco_g'><span type='text' id='valor_21 valor_CSS' readonly>Valor: </span></div>

      <input class='quant_g-21 quant_g' id='quanti_g' type='number' name='quant_g' value='10' required min='10' />

    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

eu preciso somar o meu input number e o valor do meu select e substituir o meu span pela multiplicação do input e do select.

Comment: Quando voce usa o ```document.getElementById('valor_21').value = valor_total_21``` esta  acontecendo esse erro porque não existe um elemento com esse id, aparamente essa é classa do input e não o id, então no caso fica desse jeito ```document.getElementById('quanti_g').value = valor_total_21```

Comment: consegui mt obrigado